# .Net 5 Blazor Server AD Group Authorization issue

Tags: asp.net-core, ntlm, .net-5, asp.net5

I can't get my Blazor Server app to honor AD Group membership, I can get it to read my User ID so I assume NTLM is working but it doesn't seem to recognise me as bing in a group.

I've trid IIS and IIS Expresss

launchSettings.json

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58855",
      "sslPort": 44394
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {      
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AppName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ADRoleOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("DOMAIN\\GroupName"));

            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                //app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

Then in one of my Razor pages I have the following, as I said even int he NotAuthorized section my UserName is still displayed

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="ADRoleOnly">
    <Authorized>
        @context.User.Identity.Name is authorized.
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @context.User.Identity.Name is not authorized.
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

<AuthorizeView Roles="DOMAIN\\GroupName">
    <Authorized>
        @context.User.Identity.Name is authorized.
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @context.User.Identity.Name is not authorized.
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Currently I've rolled my own security that just hides all the content at the shared layout page but I don't like it, it's slow and you should never write your own security model if you can help it, a) I won't keep it up to date and b) it's more likely to have a bug in it than anything else.

I would really like to know what I have missed for this to not be working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't I feel stupid now, the group I was trying to Authorize against was only a Distribution Group in AD and not a Secuirty Group. I've used a different group and it's now working fine.